# Can I apply caulk over exterior wood filler?

Tags: windows, trim, adhesive, caulking, wood-filler

I am re-caulking trim that is over T-111 siding over my window that faces the brunt force of winds and rain in the Pacific Northwest.
There were leaks over the window that appeared to be coming in through this joint.

The original caulking was OSI QUAD and has been hellacious to remove.  It takes strands of siding with it and specks of it are still embedded in spots.  Have been using dental tools to remove. If there is even a small area where the new caulk wont stick, the project is doomed.

I am worried about the gaps in the T-111 that go behind the trim and am wondering if I filled the gaps and smoothed the wood surface with Elmers carpenter wood filler (*interior/exterior*) or some other type of glue whether I could apply caulk (*planning on using Big Stretch*) once the wood filler cured.

Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The OSI QUAD is the correct product to use, if you are getting leaking with that then it was not applied in all gaps and grooves of the T-111 or not done properly or the leak is higher up.

Comment: Even if the quad is not working, any moisture that would get behind it or the trim should not be getting through if the window was flashed properly. **You need to find the location/cause of the leak before proceeding**.

Comment: Thank You.  I suspect you are correct since I cant see evidence of a drip cap on the top of the window. At the underside of  the trim abutting the top of the window the only thing stopping water from coming into the area above the window is caulk.  I am not sure how to rectify at this point.

Comment: Is there trim around the window you can remove to see if there is any flashing or how the window is installed.

Comment: Yes, There is a  trim board on top of the window- 3.5 in by 3/4 inch thick..  When the caulking under the trim was removed because it was cracking there was big gap right above the window about 3/8 inch.  I recaulked thinking that was the problem after I found that taking a hose and spraying the siding right above the window resulted in a leak.  That made me think that it wasnt coming from high up.   However, still had some leakage with recent storm.   The paint on the top of the trim was lifting up in spots which made me think that joint needed to be recaulked.

Comment: I defintely can see drip cap over a deck door but none over any of the windows which protrude out with beveled edges.  I wonder whether there is a structural reason why the contractor never installed drip cap due to window design?